# Groovy - Ignore extra attributes in a map during object instantiation

Tags: dictionary, groovy, constructor, attributes

Is there a way to make groovy ignore extra attributes in a map during object instantiation? Example:

```
class Banana{
    String name
}
def params = [name:'someGuy', age:13]
new Banana(params)
```

In this example, groovy throws a No such property: age exception (obviously because age isn't defined in the Banana class. Without resorting to manually mapping only the desired attributes from the map to the constructor of the Banana class, is there a way to tell Banana to ignore the extra attributes?

I noticed that Grails domain classes do not suffer from this problem, and I would like the same behavior here!

Thanks for your help and advice!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no built in way to do this in groovy.  Grails does it by generating its own constructors for domain objects.  A simple workaround is to use a constructor like this:

```
Banana(Map map) {
    metaClass.setProperties(this, map.findAll { key, value -> this.hasProperty(key) })
}
```

Comment: Obviously, you have to make sure your params map does not contain the keys `class` or `metaClass`, or Exceptions/weirdness will ensue ;-)

Comment: Thank you - I enjoy this feature of grails, I was hoping it wasn't through clever tricks but was a language feature instead. Oh well. Your workaround should do the trick though, thanks!

Answer (score 23):

There is a simpler way to deal with this case.

In your bean, just implement a trait

```
trait IgnoreUnknownProperties {
    def propertyMissing(String name, value){
        // do nothing
    }
}

class Person implements IgnoreUnknownProperties {
    String name
}

map = ["name": "haha", "extra": "test"]
Person p = new Person(map)

println p.name
```

Comment: I have used this approach successfully in the Groovy console (v2.4.8) but when I try to do the same in my Groovy project I get a java.lang.VerifyError complaining about the method signature of propertyMissing?! Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: to anyone wondering why this works, this bypasses the initial error which is a `MissingPropertyException`. This exception is thrown automatically by the [invokeMissingPropery() method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClass.html#invokeMissingProperty(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,boolean)) during the object instanciation. As stated in the doc, this method will either call `propertyMissing()`, or throw a `MissingProperty` exception if `propertyMissing()` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Another way that does not impact performance if all properties are present:

```
public static Banana valueOf(Map<String, Object> params) {
    try {
        return new Banana(source)
    } catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage())
        source.remove(e.property)
        return valueOf(source)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @JiankuanXing's answer (which is a perfect answer `:)` ), but instead of using [`trait`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-traits.html) your class can extends [`Expando`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Expando.html) and add the `propertyMissing` method:

```
class Banana extends Expando {
    String name

    def propertyMissing(name, value) {
        // nothing
    }
}
def params = [name:'someGuy', age:13]
new Banana(params)
```

The use of `trait` fits probably better this case since it allow behavior composition and you can add the `trait` to all the class object which need it. I only add this alternative since `Expando` can be used since `groovy 1.5` version while `traits` are introduced in [`groovy 2.3`](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.3.html).

Hope it helps,